# Output of `sequence` Function

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world) discusses the `sequence` function with IO.

```
ghci> sequence (map print [1,2,3,4,5])  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
[(),(),(),(),()]
```

The book discusses:

> What's with the [(),(),(),(),()] at the end? Well, when we evaluate an
>   I/O action in GHCI, it's performed and then its result is printed out,
>   unless that result is (), in which case it's not printed out.

I don't fully understand why the result is `[(),...,()]`. Based on this sentence, `unless that result is (), in which case it's not printed out.`

Yet `1..5` prints out, so why is `()` returned?

Comment: Look at the type signatures: `map print [1,2,3,4,5]` is of type `[IO ()]` and `sequence` is of type `Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`. Hence `sequence (map print [1,2,3,4,5])` is of type `IO [()]`. I think what you want is `mapM_` which is of the type `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`. Hence you could simply do: `mapM_ print [1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: why, then, doesn't the following return `5 ()` instead of just printing `5`? `ghci> let x = print 5 | ghci> :t x
x :: IO () |
ghci> x 5`

Comment: `[()]` is not `()`.  So `IO [()]` isn't `IO ()`. If an expression's type is the latter, ghci skips printing the result of executing it. But that's irrelevant in the former case.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `sequence (map print [1..5])` is `[(), (), (), (), ()]`, not `()`.

If you use `sequence_ (map print [1..5])`, which has a `()` result, you will not see its result in GHCi.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are being confused because ghci will happily print out the value of any `IO a` where a is not (), example:

```
Prelude> import System.Time
Prelude System.Time> let x = getClockTime
Prelude System.Time> x
Fri Jun 13 16:53:34 EDT 2014
```

But this is not the behavior when running code outside of ghci, unless you subsequently wrote:

```
x >>= print
```

Just follow the types and you'll see that the result of running sequence gives you a value of type `IO [()]` (which ghci will happily print since its not of type `IO ()`

```
ghci> :t sequence
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]

ghci> :t sequence_
sequence_ :: Monad m => [m a] -> m ()

ghci> :t mapM_ print
mapM_ print :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
```

So you can do:

```
ghci> sequence_ (map print [1..5])
1
2
3
4
5
ghci> mapM_ print [1..5]
1
2
3
4
5
```